# Given two list of words, than return as dictionary and set together

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hey (Sorry bad english) so am going to try and make my question more clear. if i have a function let's say create_username_dict(name_list, username_list). which takes in two list's 1 being the name_list with names of people than the other list being usernames that is made out of the names of people. what i want to do is take does two list than convert them to a dictonary and set them together.
like this:

```
>>> name_list = ["Ola Nordmann", "Kari Olsen", "Roger Jensen"]
>>> username_list = ["alejon", "carli", "hanri"]
>>> create_username_dict(name_list, username_list)
{
    "Albert Jones": "alejon",
    "Carlos Lion": "carli",
    "Hanna Richardo": "hanri"
}
```

i have tried look around on how to connect two different list in too one dictonary, but can't seem to find the right solution

Comment: Show your work ? Also how are the mapping done . Is the first element in name_list maps to the first element in username_list ?

Comment: Where did you get Albert Jones, Carlos Lion and Hanna Richardo from?

Comment: Your names in `name_list` and in dictionary key values don't match, but if you want 1 to 1 mapping between indexes in the list, you can loop over and create a dictionary.

Comment: Forgot to change the 3 first words in name_list too Alber jones, Carlos Lion and Hanna Richardo sorry my bad. But thanks for all the respons am very new two python and i am greatful for all response

Answer (score 0):

If both lists are in matching order, i.e. the i-th element of one list corresponds to the i-th element of the other, then you can use this

```python
D = dict(zip(name_list, username_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair the list.

```
d = {key: value for key,value in zip(name_list, username_list)}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Ola Nordmann': 'alejon', 'Kari Olsen': 'carli', 'Roger Jensen': 'hanri'}
```

Comment: Oh, well... just to clarify, when I put this answer, I had not seen @AlexP answer... Should I delete my answer? It would be great if somebody advised me because I don't want a downvote in my answer

Comment: If you get downvotes, then delete it, if downvotes affect you. I think then it gets restored :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering both the list are same length and one to one mapping

```
name_list = ["Ola Nordmann", "Kari Olsen", "Roger Jensen"]
username_list = ["alejon", "carli", "hanri"]
result_stackoverflow = dict()
for index, name in enumerate(name_list):
    result_stackoverflow[name] = username_list[index]
print(result_stackoverflow)
>>> {'Ola Nordmann': 'alejon', 'Kari Olsen': 'carli', 'Roger Jensen': 'hanri'}
```

Answer by @alex does the same but maybe too encapsulated for a beginner. So this is the verbose version.

Comment: thank you soo much. i can use this further

Comment: Approve the answer if you are ok with it. However some points to think when you handling this question : 1. How is the mapping being done ? 2. Can I use  assert functionality or other sanity function to make sure the conditions are being held. Best of luck for your journey.